# How to install a preview release of Ruby with RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

Is it possible to install preview releases of Ruby through RVM? If it is, how can I do it?

RVM's [Installing](https://rvm.io/rubies/installing) page only shows how to install maintained versions, patch levels & from head but now preview versions, but doesn't mention anything about preview releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing preview versions are similar to installing patch versions:

> rvm install {Ruby Version + Preview Version}

For example, you can install 2.6 Preview 2 with `rvm install 2.6.0-preview2`.

*To find out find available versions, visit https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/.*

Comment: You may need to update `rvm` in order for the new versions to show up.